# Conditional if else Problem

Tags: conditionals, ifelse

I have an additional title called {long_titles}, but do not use it for every entry. However, when I do use it, I want to suppress the {title}. I have tried several approaches but can't get it.  Needs some help!

```
{if "{long_titles:count}" != ""}    
      <h3>{title}</h3>{/if}         
      {if:else}
<h3>{long_titles}</h3>{/if}
```

Comment: ```<h3>{if long_titles <> ""}{long_titles}{if:else}{title}{/if}</h3>```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<h3>
{if long_titles}
    {long_titles}
{if:else}
    {title}
{/if}
</h3>
```